# how to check which functions are the most worked on in a git repository

Tags: git

I want to find out which functions are the most worked on in a git repository. Is that possible ?

Basically I want to find out which function in all the code files in a git repository have the most commits by developers.
Please let me know. It will be great help.
Many thanks.

Comment: With "function" you mean "method"? Since people commit files, this will not be easy to accomplish. Does not make a lot of sense either I fear...

Answer (score 0):

I looked at some documentation and I believe [git blame](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) will fit some of your needs. Try starting with this and check out the other command line arguments to define what you’re looking for.

`git blame -L<funcname>`

As far as testing which ones are modified most a simple script in your environment could probably fill that void.